# Field strength tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, gauge-theory, lie-algebra, yang-mills

This question seems very simple however I'm stuck:
given the following:
How can we find those components? And how can we check the antisymmetry of $F$?
The equations are from Nakahara, *Geometry, Topology and Physics*.

$$
\mathcal A_\mu=A_\mu{}^\alpha T_\alpha \quad \mathcal{F}_{\mu\nu}=F_{\mu\nu}{}^\alpha T_\alpha\tag{10.40}
\\ [T_\alpha, T_\beta]=f_{\alpha\beta}{}^\gamma T_\gamma
$$
$$
\\F_{\mu\nu}{}^\alpha=\partial_\mu A_\nu{}^\alpha-\partial_\nu A_\mu{}^\alpha+f_{\beta\gamma}{}^\alpha A_\mu{}^\beta A_\nu{}^\gamma\tag{10.41}
$$

Comment: I included a picture because I didn't know how to write the indices.(sorry)

Comment: Indices can be written as F^{\mu \nu} and F_{\mu \nu}, for instance.

Comment: Nihar has kindly edited your post, but for the future you can find a tutorial on basic MathJax synax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by “How can we find those components?”

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to check the antisymmetry of $F$ is to write it as
$$
\mathcal{F}_{\mu \nu} = \partial_\mu \mathcal{A}_\nu - \partial_\nu \mathcal{A}_\mu + [ \mathcal{A}_\mu , \mathcal{A}_\nu]
$$
This is manifestly antisymmetric, because the commutator is antisymmetric. Note then that
\begin{align}
[ \mathcal{A}_\mu , \mathcal{A}_\nu] &= [A_\mu^a T_a, A_\nu^b T_b] \\
&= [T_a, T_b] A_\mu^a A_\nu^b \\
&= f^c_{\; ab}T_c A_\mu^a A_\nu^b
\end{align}
which allows us to match the original expression with the one you provided.

In particular, from the definition
$$
[T_a, T_b] = f^c_{\; ab} T_c
$$
we can see that
$$
f^c_{\; ab} = -f^c_{\; ba}.
$$